# Loading dataURL from Local Storage into HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having a bit of trouble loading a dataURL into my canvas from local storage.

```
localStorage.getItem(canvasArea)
```

I've managed to save the dataURL into local storage and when I console.log it out I can view it:

[image: local storage which save the canvas in a dataURL]

I managed to save it by using this code:

```
document.getElementById("saveButton").addEventListener("click", function()
{  
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasArea"),
   ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   localStorage.setItem(canvasArea, canvas.toDataURL());
})
```

However when I try and place that dataURL using the code below it doesn't do anything.

```
function loadCanvas(dataURL) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasArea');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = dataURL;
    imageObj.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    };  
}

var dataURL = localStorage.getItem(canvasArea);
loadCanvas(dataURL);
```

Am I missing something obvious or am I being stupid?
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `localStorage.getItem(canvasArea);`  - this code refers to undefined variable `canvasArea` which is casted to empty string (`''`)

Comment: You should probably use quotes around the keys, as they should be strings ?

Comment: @hindmost, actually, since `"canvasArea"` is the `id` of OP's canvas Element, `canvasArea` is not undefined, but equivalent to `document.getElementById('canvasArea') || document.getElementsByName('canvasArea')[0];` which, once passed into the `setItem()` and `getItem()` methods, will be converted to its string notation : `"[object HTMLCanvasElement]"`. So, even if it is certainly not what OP was trying to do, it will work... Now, for the actual issue, I'm guessing there are some other oddities into OP's code that we don't see here.

Comment: @Hopeless, could you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduces the issue ?

Comment: @Kaiido Frankly I can't understand what you wrote about. Do you really  mean that any undefined identifier usage should result to `document.getElementById()` call? Then when does [Reference Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) occur?

Comment: @Kaiido Weirdly it works on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezzbckjp/) so must be something dodgy on my end :( i'll have to take a deeper look

Comment: @Kaiido Could you provide any evidence/reference?

Comment: @Kaiido Maybe. Although I think that's not cross-browser behaviour. At least I don't see such in my Firefox (get ReferenceError instead).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Answer (score 0):

Do `console.log` on `localStorage.getItem(canvasArea)` and see exactly what it's getting. I've had weird issues like that before where it wanted `loadCanvas(""+ dataURL);` instead of `loadCanvas(dataURL);`

Comment: It returned: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA and so on, which when clicked it showed the image that I saved, the green one

Comment: In your function loadCanvas, hardcode the image URL instead of taking it as a parameter and see if it works. If it does you'll know there's an issue with the URL, it will narrow it down

Comment: I just tried                                                                                                     var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = "http://i.imgur.com/nXjDbCM.jpg";
imageObj.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
 }; but no change

Comment: Why not just append to the image to the container instead?